# Encapsulate/hide a secret in a python module

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently I'm running a microservice that does some transformation involving a secret with a string it receives and returns the new string. So the data is moved across the network to the function.

However, to improve the performance, its preferable if the function comes to the data. It would be great to have a local python module (we are set to python here) that performs the transformation and only receives the secret at initialisation.

So now the question: How can I store (temporarily) the secret in a way, that the user of the module is not able to read it? Its not a strong secret, so it does not need fancy crypto here. But it should prevent the user from reading it without any effort, as the python "private" class variable allows.

Comment: I would suggest reading the secret from a file at run-time, rather than embedding it anywhere in your code, but if the code is on the same disk as the secret, that implies the user can read from the same file with or without Python.

Answer (score 0):

Since the user can presumably just edit the module to intercept the secret as it's being received from the network, and see how it's accessed, there's not much to gain security-wise from obfuscating how it's stored.

Either way, if you really do want to do this, I'd suggest sneaking it into somewhere else than your module; for instance, you could slip it into the namespace of a builtin module like `sys`... But again, the moment someone reads your module's code (either from the .py or by decompiling), they will see what's happening.